# Poco C++: Poco::Crypto::RSAKey class is deprecated. How to encrypt plain text with private key?

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptography, poco-libraries

For a my personal C++ project, I'd like been able to encrypt plain text data using private key. In my project I make an extensive usage of **Poco C++ library**, and I'd like handle such feature with it.

Currently I am successfully handling a private key file in order to create [Poco::Crypto::RSAKey](https://docs.pocoproject.org/current/Poco.Crypto.RSAKey.html).

```
std::filesystem::path keyFile = std::filesystem::path("MyFile");
Poco::SharedPtr<Poco::Crypto::RSAKey> key(new Poco::Crypto::RSAKey("", keyFile.string()));
Poco::Crypto::CipherFactory& factory = Poco::Crypto::CipherFactory::defaultFactory();
Poco::Crypto::Cipher* pRSACipher = factory.createCipher(*key.get());
std::string plainText("MyTextToEncrypt");
std::string encrypted =  pRSACipher->encryptString(plainText, Poco::Crypto::Cipher::ENC_BASE64_NO_LF);
```

Having a look at [official Poco documentation](https://docs.pocoproject.org/current/Poco.Crypto.RSAKey.html) I found out that both [Poco::Crypto::RSAKey](https://docs.pocoproject.org/current/Poco.Crypto.RSAKey.html) and [Poco::Crypto::ECKey](https://docs.pocoproject.org/current/Poco.Crypto.ECKey.html) are deprecated. Looking for an alternative to such deprecated classes both in Poco documentation and all around in web, I could not understand why such classes are declared as deprecated. Moreover I could not find which classes shouold replace them.

In same time, reading [Poco::Crypto::CipherFactory](https://docs.pocoproject.org/current/Poco.Crypto.CipherFactory.html) documentation, it is not depracted using methods which get [Poco::Crypto::RSAKey](https://docs.pocoproject.org/current/Poco.Crypto.RSAKey.html) for method [Poco::Crypto::CipherFactory::createCipher](https://docs.pocoproject.org/current/Poco.Crypto.CipherFactory.html#165).

Please, can somebody tell me if using Poco::Crypto::RSAKey is still advisable, or another class should be used? And which one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suspect Poco authors want the same renovation that OpenSSL did; i.e. using the EVP interface instead. Note: I generally use OpenSSL directly; not Poco, so take that for what it's worth.

Comment: The "why" is always hard to answer; probably better to ask the developers through a mailing list / bug report system (indicate what to use for deprecated methods would be a good documentation update) or whatever. I second @WhozCraig 's educated guess, but I don't know Poco either.

Comment: @WhozCraig I will explore EVP. Thanks for your hint

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I'll contact Poco support in order to clarify their intentions in documentation. Thanks!